# How to write data stream to json file using node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am using node-osmosis to scrape some data from a website. I want to write the data to the json file. But it seems the data is keep comming and the file only write at the first time. I am using node-jsonfile to write data  to file. By the way there is a end function when the scraping is done. But I have tried it, and if it encounter a error the done will never be called and the data is lost.

```
osmosis
.data(function(listing) {
    jsonfile.writeFileSync(file, listing);
})
```

So how to write new data into the file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about osmosis, but usually '.data' is referred to a Stream when the data arrives, so you would need to create a WriteStream into the file you want the results and close it on the end callback. But as I can see in the wiki they describe it like they call the function just once... and it will contain the entire result, so maybe you are not scrapping the info you want... Maybe you need to rethink the css selectors or whatever you are using.

Good luck!

Comment: I have watched the logo, it is scraping the info I want. And if I print the listing data, it contains all the info I want. Since you mentioned I need to create a write stream, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using npm called ['jsonfile'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile).
So basically to initially start working you'll need:

```
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
```

To read from a file:

```
 jsonfile.readFile('yourJSON.json', function (err, data) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
//Your code goes here, data is that actual JSON file.
});
```

To Write file:

```
//data is a variable holding the data you want to write.
 jsonfile.writeFileSync('yourJSON.json', data);
```

You will also need body-parser as npm to parse the data.